# How do I get the MS Azure postgresql url so I can test it in the postman?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure

I created a postgres database in MS Azure and connected it with my node.js using:

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
  user: "postgres@serenify",
  password: "20001225Dhc!",
  database: "serenifyvtwo",
  host: "serenify.postgres.database.azure.com",
  port: 5432,
  ssl: true,
});
pool.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});

module.exports = pool;`
```

and I wrote the routes and try to test it in the postman to check the connections. But the postman always gives me Error: socket hang up. I dont know how to solve it.

How am I able to find the url link that I can use to test in the postman, also in the node.js to fetch the data for the react app?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced according to your requirement. I have created a postgres database in azure portal.

[image]

Then I created a node JS application in my environment that can access the database.

By using `npm install pg` we can install node modules for postgresql. By the below code you can create the table and the required data.

```
client.connect();

client.query(`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT,
        email TEXT
        )

`, (err, res) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('Table created successfully');

client.query(`
    INSERT INTO users (name, email)
    VALUES
        ('Amul Icecream', 'amulicecream@example.com'),
        ('cadbury Chocolate', 'cadburychocolate@example.com')

`, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Data inserted successfully');
```

I am able to create and store my data in my postgres database.

[image]

I have updated your given code in my environment, I can retrieve the data by giving get request. Check below for the full code.

```
const  express = require('express');
const { Client } = require('pg');

const  app = express();

const  client = new  Client({
    user:  '@@@@',
    host:  '@@@@.#####.database.azure.com',
    database:  '%%%%%',
    password:  '******',
    port:  5432,
    ssl:  true
});

client.connect();

client.query(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    email TEXT
)`, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw  err;
console.log('Table created successfully');
});

// Define a route for getting all users
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {

    client.query('SELECT * FROM users', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw  err;
        res.json(data.rows);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

[image]

I have checked in postman to get the data from database. Below is the result.

[image]